# Advice on storing file data in a Dictionary or List and performance on the compare

Tags: .net, list, file-io, dictionary, arraylist

I have a backup program which has been used internally for two years now, and I'm looking to improve the performance.

Lets use my computer as an example:

On my machine it takes roughly 7-10 seconds to generate the initial list of 19,000 files it needs to evaluate.

It then takes around 25-30 seconds to compare that list of files to the list of files that have been previously backed up in the backup location.  The comparison is strictly on the last modified time from the system to be backed up to the version that was previously backed up.  In this way it performs only an incremental backup.

I was originally only storing the full file name and then creating a fileinfo link to the file to get the data I needed.

I have since created a structure that has the 5 fields from the file I need, and have changed the list to a dictionary with the full filename as the key and the value is the structure.

The time it takes is roughly the same when I store the data in an Arraylist, List, or Dictionary so apparently my compare is the intensive task and not how I'm storing my data.

My question for you guys is Dictionary appropriate for the type of data I'm storing.  All of the full file names are unique, and I really don't care about sorting or the order of backing up data.

Below are some descriptions of the lists and the compare sub that seems to slow down the most:

- _filelistSRC is the list of files that were found in the folders to be backed up
- _fileListDES is the list of files that were found in the backup folder
- _fileList is the list which contains file that have changed since the last backup, and that should be backed up
- fileInfoS is the structure with only the information I need for each file
- fm is a class that has common file management methods I use

Private Sub Comparelists()

```
           For Each _file As KeyValuePair(Of String, fileInfoS) In _FileListSRC
            Dim dest As String

            Try
                Dim fi As fileInfoS = _file.Value

                If fi.FullName.Contains(p_UserProfile) Then
                    dest = fi.FullName.Replace(p_UserProfile & "\", p_BackupLocation)
                Else
                    dest = fi.FullName.Replace(fi.FolderRootName, p_BackupLocation)
                End If

                If _FileListDES.ContainsKey(dest) Then
                    If fm.fileLastWriteCompare(fi.LastModified, dest) Then
                        _FileList.Add(fi.FullName, fi)
                        _totalSize = _totalSize + fi.Size
                    End If
                Else
                    If Not fm.FileExists(fi.FullName) Then Continue For
                    _FileList.Add(fi.FullName, fi)
                    _totalSize = _totalSize + fi.Size
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
```

Thanks again for any help provided.

Joshua

Comment: How often is `FileExists` called? If it's called a lot, that's going to be your limiting factor.

Comment: It appears that the check for the FileExists will be called everytime it finds a file that hasn't been backed up before.

If it's not in the Destination File scan list, I'm not sure I need to do this check everytime but there is probably a good reason I put it in there.

I'll remove and run some test to see if it causes any ill effects.

Comment: So 35 seconds with `File.Exists`, and 7 seconds without it?

Comment: The processing time with the FileExists for the 19,000 files was 7 seconds to read all of the files into the lists, and 28 seconds to do the compare. With FileExists check turned off the processing time was still 7 seconds to read all of the files into the lists, but the compare took less than a second. That made a huge difference :) Now to see if there are any ill effects. Thanks alot @Jim Mischel

Sorry I had to delete my original comment but it went from 35 seconds total to 7 seconds total.  Which is awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary seems appropriate to me, as it uses hashing to store the data which allow for quick get of objects.does it reduce your processing time? if it does, what is your concern?

Comment: I couldn't really see a difference in processing time by switching it from a Arraylist to a Dictionary but I was tracking seconds for debugging and not ticks or milliseconds.